# How to show/hide JavaFX app macOS dock icon at runtime?

Tags: java, macos, javafx

So when my JavaFX app gets minimized to the system tray, I want it to be removed from the macOS dock/app switcher. If they click the system tray icon, then select "Open Application", I want it to show up in the macOS dock/app switcher, all without relaunching the app.

I've tried using the undocumented `PlatformImpl.setTaskbarApplication(false)`, but it doesn't seem to do anything until a relaunch.

I've also tried packaging it into a .app file and adding:

```
<key>LSUIElement</key>
<string>1</string>
```

to the info.plist file but it also doesn't work until a relaunch.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this question?

Comment: That should work, but should do before the UI is shown.
Also you can use rococoa library and set one of the properties to hide/show icons. (                    setActivationPolicy(NSApplication.NSApplicationActivationPolicy.NSApplicationActivationPolicyAccessory.ordinal)